# How to customize rich faces default css?

Tags: jsf-2

I am new to Rich Faces.  We are having a form with validations.  We are using rich:message to display the error messages.  If the user doesn't enter data and if he clicks save, then validation messages will be displayed.  As I am using rich:message, the error message has an error message followed by the text.

How can I remove the error image and also how can i change the style of font?

Please hlep me on this.

Comment: did you check the tag specifications at [link](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_message.html), there is a link in the last that how to use custom css classes with richfaces tags.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways for changing styles and font:

1. With skins
2. With CSS

Skin allows you to customize *some* styles (like font), but not everything. To create your own skin, add a `yourskinname.skin.properties` in `META-INF/skins` directory. Also, add the following lines in `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.skin</param-name>
    <param-value>yourskinname</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For the content, copy the content of one file of the `META-INF/skins` folder of `richfaces-core-impl-4.0.0-Final.jar`, and change the properties you want.
You may provide only a subset of properties, by adding "`baseSkin=name of base skin`" in your file: the properties not described in your file will be retrieved from the base skin.

For instance, to change the fonts to "Calibri 13px", your file would look like :

```
baseSkin = DEFAULT
generalSizeFont=13px
generalFamilyFont=Calibri 

# Fonts
headerSizeFont=13px
headerFamilyFont=Calibri 

tabSizeFont=13px
tabFamilyFont=Calibri 

buttonSizeFont=13px
buttonFamilyFont=Calibri
```

For deeper explantation, look at http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Skinning_and_theming.html

But skins are not sufficient for your case (removing the error image, for instance), so you need to use CSS, as suggested by @Asad.
Personaly, I had an issue with this solution : richfaces CSS were always loaded **after** mine. I found a way of overcoming this issue: I put a `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myrichfaces.css"/>`, where I put my customized values, inside the `<body>` tag !, then my CSS is loaded after richfaces, so I can overload values.

CSS tags for messages are described here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Output_and_messages.html#sect-Component_Reference-richmessage-Style_classes_and_skin_parameters ; so, for removing the icon for error messages, you can add the following CSS statements:

```
.rf-msg-err {
    background-image: none;
}
```